# Autoit make combo show when another combo has a certain value

Tags: autoit

In my script: http://pastebin.com/Az6vabnK I am trying to make a combo show up when another combo has a certain value as seen here:

```
            Case $Combo2
                    If Read() = "Vanilla" Then
                            GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                            $Combo3 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Choose Version", 10, 85, 161, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
                            GUICtrlSetData($Combo3, "Latest|1.6.4|1.6.2|1.5.2|1.4.7|1.4.5")
                    Else
                            GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                            GUICtrlDelete($Combo3)
                    EndIf


Func Read();The function for reading the state of the server type combo.
    Return GUICtrlRead($Combo2)
EndFunc   ;==>Read
```

In the while it's a:

```
AdlibRegister("Read")
```

To read the value. For some reason, nothing happens when the combo changes value. Any ideas?

Comment: You create `$Label1` without specified width and height. That's a problem. It might overlap other controls making them invisible or inusable. **Always** make sure to specify width and height for all of your controls or you might run into unwanted issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete that AdlibRegister("Read") because it does nothing. 
You are already getting value of $combo2 here

```
If Read() = "Vanilla" Then
```

$Combo2 should be a global variable or you can remove that Read() function and use GuiCtrlRead directly

```
If GUICtrlRead($Combo2) = "Vanilla" Then
```

Try this

```
                If GUICtrlRead($Combo2) = "Vanilla" Then
                        GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                        $Combo3 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Choose Version", 10, 85, 161, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
                        GUICtrlSetData($Combo3, "Latest|1.6.4|1.6.2|1.5.2|1.4.7|1.4.5")
                        GUICtrlCreateTabItem("")
                Else
                        GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                        GUICtrlDelete($Combo3)
                EndIf
```

Comment: It worked, but it doesn't show the combo before I change tab and change back again.

Comment: Make sure there isn't any control overlapping.
When you select Vanilla, go click on the spot where it should appear.

Comment: Also, in the future, consider hiding and showing the controls instead create/delete.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click where it should be. There are no control overlapping except from the tab it's created on. I tried hiding and showing it instead, but it didn't show at all.

Comment: To create a new control on an existing tabitem use GUISwitch($hWin,$tabitem) to select it and just create your new control. Don't forget to close your tabitem creation with GUICtrlCreateTabItem("").

Comment: Please read my updated code. You don't seem to understand the problem.

Comment: It seems I have to write it down here...
                If GUICtrlRead($Combo2) = "Vanilla" Then
                        GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                        $Combo3 = GUICtrlCreateCombo("Choose Version", 10, 85, 161, 25, $CBS_DROPDOWNLIST)
                        GUICtrlSetData($Combo3, "Latest|1.6.4|1.6.2|1.5.2|1.4.7|1.4.5")
                        GUICtrlCreateTabItem("")
                Else
                        GUISwitch($GUI, $TabSheet2)
                        GUICtrlDelete($Combo3)
                EndIf

Comment: @EpicKnarvik97 You need to add GUICtrlCreateTabItem("") after the creation of your new combo!